# Laravel 5.4 Can I use DB-Transaction using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Can I use TRANSACTION of LARAVEL 5.4 to combine eloquent and query builder ?

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);

    DB::table('posts')->delete();
});
    $formula = new Formula
    $formula->prepared_by       = '1';
    $formula->date_prepared     = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila');
    $formula->time_prepared     = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila');
    $formula->status            = 'pending';

    $formula->save();
```

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to move the `$formula` calls into the `DB::transaction` block.

Comment: @ceejayoz so it means that the eloquent itself will be rolled back if the whole query wasn't executed properly ?

Comment: Yes. Feel free to test.

Comment: Great thanks @ceejayoz its works but everything inside the transaction isnt reading the parameter esp Request $request

Comment: Yes, because of http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. Pass any variables you need within the transition function by doing `DB::transaction(function () use($foo, $bar) {`

Comment: so Ill send it as a parameter Thanks for this will try it now.

Comment: it works thanks @ceejayoz